# Is there a Python 'shortcut' to define a class variable equal to a string version of its own name?

Tags: python, string, variable-assignment

This is a bit of a silly thing, but I want to know if there is concise way in Python to define class variables that contain string representations of their own names.  For example, one can define:

```
class foo(object):
    bar = 'bar'
    baz = 'baz'
    baf = 'baf'
```

Probably a more concise way to write it in terms of lines consumed is:

```
class foo(object):
    bar, baz, baf = 'bar', 'baz', 'baf'
```

Even there, though, I still have to type each identifier twice, once on each side of the assignment, and the opportunity for typos is rife.

What I want is something like what `sympy` provides in its `var` method:

```
sympy.var('a,b,c')
```

The above injects into the namespace the variables `a`, `b`, and `c`, defined as the corresponding `sympy` symbolic variables.

Is there something comparable that would do this for plain strings?

```
class foo(object):
    [nifty thing]('bar', 'baz', 'baf')
```

**EDIT:** To note, I want to be able to access these as separate identifiers in code that uses `foo`:

```
>>> f = foo(); print(f.bar)
bar
```

**ADDENDUM:** Given the interest in the question, I thought I'd provide more context on why I want to do this.  I have two use-cases at present: (1) typecodes for a set of custom exceptions (each `Exception` subclass has a distinct typecode set); and (2) lightweight enum.  My desired feature set is:

1. Only having to type the typecode / enum name (or value) once in the source definition. `class foo(object): bar = 'bar'` works fine but means I have to type it out twice in-source, which gets annoying for longer names and exposes a typo risk.
2. Valid typecodes / enum values exposed for IDE autocomplete.
3. Values stored internally as comprehensible strings:

   1. For the `Exception` subclasses, I want to be able to define `myError.__str__` as just something like `return self.typecode + ": " + self.message + " (" + self.source + ")"`, without having to do a whole lot of `dict`-fu to back-reference an `int` value of `self.typecode` to a comprehensible and meaningful string.
   2. For the enums, I want to just be able to obtain `widget` as output from `e = myEnum.widget; print(e)`, again without a lot of `dict`-fu.

      - I recognize this will increase overhead. My application is not speed-sensitive (GUI-based tool for driving a separate program), so I don't think this will matter at all.
4. Straightforward membership testing, by also including (say) a `frozenset` containing all of the typecodes / enum string values as `myError.typecodes`/`myEnum.E` classes.  This addresses potential problems from accidental (or intentional.. but why?!) use of an invalid typecode / enum string  via simple sanity checks like `if not enumVal in myEnum.E: raise(ValueError('Invalid enum value: ' + str(enumVal)))`.
5. Ability to import individual enum / exception subclasses via, say, `from errmodule import squirrelerror`, to avoid cluttering the namespace of the usage environment with non-relevant exception subclasses.  I believe this prohibits any solutions requiring post-twiddling on the module level like what Sinux proposed.
6. For the enum use case, I would rather avoid introducing an additional package dependency since I don't (think I) care about any extra functionality available in the official `enum` class. In any event, it still wouldn't resolve #1.

I've already figured out implementation I'm satisfied with for all of the above but #1.  My interest in a solution to #1 (without breaking the others) is partly a desire to typo-proof entry of the typecode / enum values into source, and partly plain ol' laziness.  (Says the guy who just typed up a gigantic SO question on the topic.)

Comment: How about using ``namedtuple``(s)?

Comment: This seems like an odd requirement. Why do you need this?

Comment: @JamesMills Ahh, yeah, `namedtuple` might do it. I knew about them, actually, but hadn't thought of using them this way.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Heh. "Need" is a strong word for it. Like I said, "bit of a silly thing."  I'm (thoroughly non-Pythonically) using my own lightweight approach to enum.

Comment: @Brian: Have you considered using [enums](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html)? They're a Python 3.4 feature with a [backported version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) for Python 2 and Python 3 versions before 3.4.

Comment: @user2357112 I did, but wanted to try a lighter-weight approach that didn't require another package dependency, before I went that route.  Actually, though Enum doesn't really help, because one still has to type in values for the various enum identifiers.

Comment: When `enum` was being discussed for addition to the stdlib, about 69105 different enum libraries were built and uploaded to PyPI or posted on ActiveState to demonstrate all the possible features, including string enums that don't require a value. Even if you don't want to actually _use_ one of them, you can look through the code to see all the different ways of doing all the different things similar to what you asked for.

Comment: @abarnert Good to know; is there a clearinghouse somewhere where links to all those various implementations could be found? PEP thread, maybe?

Comment: An [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for sure...

Comment: @ŁukaszR. Yeah, probably so. D'you think I should split the Addendum to a new question?  I'm still interested in an answer to my unedited OP as a curiosity... I get the impression the answer is 'No'.

Comment: @Brian: As far as I know, no actual clearinghouse, but yeah, following from [PEP 435](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/) to the linked -ideas and -dev threads should get you to most of them if you're willing to skim through all those messages…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields):

**Example:**

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple as nifty_thing
>>> Data = nifty_thing("Data", ["foo", "bar", "baz"])
>>> data = Data(foo=1, bar=2, baz=3)
>>> data.foo
1
>>> data.bar
2
>>> data.baz
3
```

**Side Note:** If you are using/on Python 3.x I'd recommend [Enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) as per @user2357112's comment. This is the standardized approach going forward for Python 3+

**Update:** Okay so if I understand the OP's *exact* requirement(s) here I think the only way to do this (*and presumably `sympy` does this too*) is to inject the names/variables into the `globals()` or `locals()` namespaces. Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


def nifty_thing(*names):
    d = globals()
    for name in names:
        d[name] = None


nifty_thing("foo", "bar", "baz")

print foo, bar, bar
```

Output:

```
$ python foo.py 
None None None
```

**NB:** *I don't really recommend this!* :)

**Update #2:** The other example you showed in your question is implemented like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import sys


def nifty_thing(*names):
    frame = sys._getframe(1)
    locals = frame.f_locals

    for name in names:
        locals[name] = None


class foo(object):

    nifty_thing("foo", "bar", "baz")


f = foo()

print f.foo, f.bar, f.bar
```

Output:

```
$ python foo.py 
None None None
```

**NB:** This is inspired by `zope.interface.implements()`.

Comment: Ahhh, but it still requires `Data(foo=1, ...)`.  I don't want to have to supply extra values for the members, and I don't want to have to instantiate a new `namedtuple` type *and* an instance of the new type every time I have the list of things.  It's quicker/easier just to type in the names twice.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to do what the OP is looking for. The attributes don't automatically hold string representations of their names, and you have to specify both name and value.

Comment: James, +1 for `import namedtuple as nifty_thing`. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I may not have accurately described what I was actually looking for in OP. (May not have had a clear idea in my head...)

Comment: @Brian That's okay :) At least you have many options to choose from!

Comment: Mm... so it might be feasible to define a helper function.... you're right, though, in my current state as a Python novice I don't really want to be injecting things manually into namespaces.

Comment: There is a cost to what's called *meta programming" -- The cost of increased levels of indirection. My tip: Learn the basics well; and only use more powerful constructs sparingly (*at all if you can help it*).

Comment: The `locals` thing doesn't work. Well, it works if you call it from the top level, but only because `locals` at the top level is actually `globals`, so it reduces to your earlier example. But in general, creating new variables in a frame's `f_locals` will not actually make them accessible in the frame's code. (Or course if you want to `ctypes` your way to the C API, there is a workaround, at least for CPython…)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *"creating new variables in a frame's f_locals will not actually make them accessible in the frame's code"* -- They are accessible in the scope where they were bound. In this case as class attributes. The ``id()`` of ``f_locals`` matches ``foo.__dict__``

Comment: [Modifying `locals` is implementation-defined and not guaranteed to work.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)

Comment: I definitely don't want to inject into global namespace.  If `locals` injection is flaky, I don't really want to go there, either.

Comment: Now that I peruse the options for a while, James, your Update #2 is the solution I'm looking for.  It's just frustrating that the locals injection approach isn't guaranteed to be robust across all Python implementations.  Ah well.

Comment: @Brian You can always have slightly different implementations depending on the platform and interpreter you're on :)

Comment: Yeah, but just typing out the strings manually will occupy fewer lines of code, be more robust, and work on all implementations.  As much as I love me a clever trick....

Comment: Sorry to swipe the rep away from you on this, but I figured out something spot-on to what I'm wanting to do.

Comment: Aaaand, rep is back. My 'solution' didn't stand up to actual usage.

Answer (score 4):

```
current_list  = ['bar', 'baz', 'baf']

class foo(object):
    """to be added"""

for i in current_list:
    setattr(foo, i, i)
```

then run this:

```
>>>f = foo()
>>>print(f.bar)
bar
>>>print(f.baz)
baz
```

Comment: This gives me what I want. I can define multiple classes in a module all with a `typecodes` variable that's a `frozenset` of strings; I can then put `for c in [class1, class2, class3, ...]: for t in c.typecodes: setattr(c,t,t)` at the end of the module. Having to tag those extra `for` loops at the end is disappointing, but I get the structure I want & it avoids risk of typos.

Comment: Ahhhh, it's not quite what I want after all.  The `setattr` call has to come on the module level, and I want to be able to `from module import foo`, in which case the module-level `for` loops won't be executed.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't work exactly like what you asked for, but it seems like it should do the job:

```
class AutoNamespace(object):
    def __init__(self, names):
        try:
            # Support space-separated name strings
            names = names.split()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        for name in names:
            setattr(self, name, name)
```

Demo:

```
>>> x = AutoNamespace('a b c')
>>> x.a
'a'
```

If you want to do what SymPy does with `var`, you can, but I would strongly recommend against it. That said, here's a function based on the source code of `sympy.var`:

```
def var(names):
    from inspect import currentframe
    frame = currentframe().f_back
    try:
        names = names.split()
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    for name in names:
        frame.f_globals[name] = name
```

Demo:

```
>>> var('foo bar baz')
>>> bar
'bar'
```

It'll always create global variables, even if you call it from inside a function or class. `inspect` is used to get at the caller's globals, whereas `globals()` would get `var`'s own globals.

Comment: I like this solution, but it doesn't quite align with how I want to use it. In particular, I don't know if subclassing `__init__` is feasible. See my edit just now to OP.

Answer (score 0):

How about you define the variable as emtpy string and then get their name:

```
class foo(object):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return item


foo = foo()
print foo['test']
```

Comment: I don't want to have to index using magic strings, or define an external library of string keys elsewhere in code.  I want the variable to appear as a class member, so that I can exploit IDE autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension of bman's idea. This has its advantages and disadvantages, but at least it does work with some autocompleters.

```
class FooMeta(type):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return attr

    def __dir__(self):
        return ['bar', 'baz', 'baf']

class foo:
    __metaclass__ = FooMeta
```

This allows access like `foo.xxx` → `'xxx'` for all `xxx`, but also guides autocomplete through `__dir__`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what I was looking for:

```
>>> class tester:
...     E = frozenset(['this', 'that', 'the', 'other'])
...     for s in E:
...         exec(str(s) + "='" + str(s) + "'") # <--- THIS
...         
>>> tester()
<__main__.tester instance at 0x03018BE8>
>>> t = tester()
>>> t.this
'this'
>>> t.that in tester.E
True
```

Only have to define the element strings once, and I'm pretty sure it will work for all of my requirements listed in the question.  In actual implementation, I plan to encapsulate the `str(s) + "='" + str(s) + "'"` in a helper function, so that I can just call `exec(helper(s))` in the `for` loop.  (I'm pretty sure that the `exec` has to be placed in the body of the class, not in the helper function, or else the new variables would be injected into the (transitory) scope of the helper function, not that of the class.)

**EDIT:** Upon detailed testing, this DOES NOT WORK -- the use of `exec` prevents the introspection of the IDE from knowing of the existence of the created variables.

Comment: *sigh* ``exec()`` seriously? :P

Comment: @JamesMills <hangs head, closes IDE, burns laptop>

Comment: Oh it's *okay*; it's not that bad :) (*yes it is!*) :P

Comment: @JamesMills In all seriousness, constructed as it is, is it a massive security hole? Or just hacktastic to the max?

Comment: That *depends* -- Do you trust the data that's being ``eval()``'d?

Comment: @JamesMills I trust (foolishly?) everything that I plan to do with it -- the only malicious way in I can think of that doesn't involve direct edits to my source is some sort of subtle subclassing maneuver.

Comment: @JamesMills Do you have anything productive to say about this or was your idiotic snark supposed to be the helpful part of your comment?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve a rather beautiful solution using metaclasses, but I'm not fluent enough in using those to present that as an answer, but I do have an option which seems to work rather nicely:

```
def new_enum(name, *class_members):                
    """Builds a class <name> with <class_members> having the name as value."""

    return type(name, (object, ), { val : val for val in class_members })

Foo = new_enum('Foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'baf')
```

This should recreate the class you've given as example, and if you want you can change the inheritance by changing the second parameter of the call to [*class* `type`(*name*, *bases*, *dict*)](//docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=type#type).